# Sonarqube 4.2 will not start but there is no logfile

Tags: sonarqube

Recently i installed the latest version of Sonar/Sonarqube (4.2), but it will not start and in /logs there is no logfile. I installed exactly like http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing.

Here are my sonar.properties

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>/sonar;databaseName=SONAR42;SelectMethod=Cursor

sonar.jdbc.username=<username>
sonar.jdbc.password=<password>

sonar.web.host=182.40.72.255
sonar.web.port=8082
sonar.web.context=/
```

Is there someone who can help me please?

Comment: You need to specify your jdbc driver class name. `sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` .. Your not getting any errors?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No errors, Nothing. The directory /logs exists, but there isn't a logfile like sonar.log. By the way i also put this in sonar.properties, but still there isn't a logfile. I saw that the service is running, but Sonarqube is not reachable in the webbrowser.

Comment: sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true is enabled in sonar.properties.

Comment: I suspect this is a UAC issue, since a log is never being created. I would try opening an elevated cmd prompt (Right click and Run as Administrator). Navigating to the directory that contains startsonar.bat, and running it from there

Comment: In my question i had not mentioned that it is a REHL 64 bit server.

Comment: Due to the comment of Cole9350 i navigate to sonar.sh and then running it. The logfile appeared.

Comment: There is another problem, but i create a new issue to start a new question.

Comment: I had the same issue and it turned out to be proxy issue